# Implement NtCreateNamedPipeFile with ctypes in Python

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, named-pipes

I'm trying to implement **NtCreateNamedPipeFile** undocumented function from NTAPI with ctypes, but I can't get it to work (I have very little experience with ctypes).

First, if I provide all arguments from function definition, I get an error "ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (4 bytes in excess)".

If I remove *NamedPipeFileHandle* argument (assuming that the handle might be what this function returns), I get "OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect".

I tried to tweak types and arguments in my implementation, but no matter what I do, I get the same WinError 87.
It's not very descriptive, so it's hard to understand what I'm doing wrong here (probably, many things).

Here's the definitions:

```
ULONG_PTR = ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM
FILE_READ_DATA = 0x00000001
FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x00000002
SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x80
FILE_CREATE = 0x00000002

def NtError(status):
    err = ntdll.RtlNtStatusToDosError(status)
    return ctypes.WinError(err)


class IO_STATUS_BLOCK(ctypes.Structure):
    class _STATUS(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = (('Status',  LONG),
                    ('Pointer', LPVOID))
    _anonymous_ = '_Status',
    _fields_ = (('_Status', _STATUS),
                ('Information', ULONG_PTR))


class UNICODE_STRING(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('Length', USHORT),
                ('MaximumLength', USHORT),
                ('Buffer', LPWSTR))

class OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('Length', ULONG),
        ('RootDirectory', HANDLE),
        ('ObjectName', UNICODE_STRING),
        ('Attributes', ULONG),
    )

ntdll = ctypes.WinDLL('ntdll')

def _decl(name, ret=None, args=()):
    fn = getattr(ntdll, name)
    fn.restype = ret
    fn.argtypes = args
    return fn

NtCreateNamedPipeFile = _decl('NtCreateNamedPipeFile', LONG,
                              (
                                   POINTER(HANDLE),
                                   DWORD,
                                   POINTER(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES),
                                   POINTER(IO_STATUS_BLOCK),
                                   ULONG,
                                   ULONG,
                                   ULONG,
                                   BOOL,
                                   BOOL,
                                   BOOL,
                                   ULONG,
                                   ULONG,
                                   ULONG,
                                   LARGE_INTEGER))
```

And the call itself:

```
handle = HANDLE()
iosb = IO_STATUS_BLOCK()

us_pipe_name = UNICODE_STRING()
us_pipe_name.Buffer = '\\??\\pipe\\' + name
us_pipe_name.Length = len(us_pipe_name.Buffer)
us_pipe_name.MaximumLength = len(us_pipe_name.Buffer)

obj_attrs = OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES()
obj_attrs.ObjectName = us_pipe_name

status = NtCreateNamedPipeFile(
    # ctypes.byref(handle),  # NamedPipeFileHandle
    FILE_READ_DATA | SYNCHRONIZE,  # DesiredAccess
    ctypes.byref(obj_attrs),  # ObjectAttributes
    ctypes.byref(iosb),  # IoStatusBlock
    0,  # ShareAccess
    FILE_CREATE,  # CreateDisposition
    0,  # CreateOptions
    0,  # WriteModeMessage
    0,  # ReadModeMessage
    1,  # NonBlocking
    1,  # MaxInstances
    1024,  # InBufferSize
    1024,  # OutBufferSize
    0,  # DefaultTimeout
)

if status != 0:
    exception = NtError(status)
    raise exception
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `NtCreateNamedPipeFile` return `NTSTATUS` code, not win32 error. it never return 87. `'\\?\\pipe\\'` - invalid path prefix. must be `'\\??\\pipe\\'` or better `'\\GLOBAL??\\pipe\\'` or more better`'\\Device\\NamedPipe\\'`. also use non-blocking mode not good idea. if need asynchronous io - use it instead non-blocking

Comment: @RbMm yes, that was a misprint with '\\?\\pipe\\', I use '??' there. And I get win32 error by using ntdll.RtlNtStatusToDosError(status) and then raising appropriate winerror, I just omitted this code, deeming it not relevant here.

Comment: @RbMm, how do you specify asyncronous mode in this function?

Comment: asynchronous mode - simply not use `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` and `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT`  in *CreateOptions* (you do this now). ` OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` have more fields.

Comment: There are some problems here. Your handling of `UNICODE_STRING` is wrong. `Length` and `MaximumLength` should be in bytes, not characters. You're missing two fields from `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` -- `SecurityDescriptor` and `SecurityQualityOfService`, and you're not initializing the `Length` field to `ctypes.sizeof(self)`. For this system call, `ShareAccess` has a special meaning. Read-Write sharing is duplex; read sharing is outbound; write sharing is inbound; and IIRC 0 sharing is an invalid parameter.

Comment: @eryksun, thank you, I'll try to see how I can fix this.

Comment: Generally, the disposition should be `FILE_OPEN_IF` (3) in case it's not the first instance. You're only allowing one instance, so for sure this is the first and `FILE_CREATE` disposition is ok.

Comment: It's more reliable in general to use generic rights. Request `GENERIC_READ` access for inbound, `GENERIC_WRITE` for outbound, and both for duplex. If you're using synchronous I/O (e.g. `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`), also request `SYNCHRONIZE` access (it's in the generic rights, but I/O manager isn't smart enough to check this). If you haven't requested `GENERIC_READ` access, then also request `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` in order to be able to query the pipe state via `NtQueryInformationFile` : `FilePipeLocalInformation`.

Comment: @eryksun, I just wanted to get something created with the simplest set of attributes, and then move up from that. But first I still don't understand, why I get "ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (4 bytes in excess)" if NamedPipeFileHandle is specified.

Comment: There's a mistake in `argtypes`. The timeout parameter should be `POINTER(LARGE_INTEGER)`. Once it's defined correctly as a pointer, then in the call using `None` for C `NULL` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks. I changed it to POINTER(LARGE_INTEGER), and then passed it as LARGE_INTEGER(0), and that error disappeared, now I only get [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, the first instance has to set a non-NULL timeout value. I don't like how ctypes automatically passes a parameter by reference that's declared as pointer type. It's more self-documenting to use `byref(LARGE_INTEGER(0))`. Also, I think passing 0 for the timeout is an invalid parameter. It has to be a relative (negative) value. FYI, `-50 * 10 * 1000`  is 50 ms, the default used in the Windows API.

Comment: @eryksun, changed it to pass byref(LARGE_INTEGER(-50 * 10 * 1000)), get the same error. But I hope it's another small step to fixing it.)

Comment: See my project: https://github.com/Biswa96/XConPty. Here I written it in C.